# Feeds: error when importing hierarchical taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

While i am trying to import taxonomies with this structure: 
name,guid,parent_name,parent_guid 
Primary Energy,32001,, 
Transformation,32002,,
Final Energy,32003,, 
Electricity,32004,Transformation,32002 
Generation efficiency,32005,Electricity,32004 
Installed capacity,32006,Electricity,32004 
Heat,32007,Transformation,32002

I am getting this error: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1018-0' for key 'PRIMARY' 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1019-0' for key 'PRIMARY' 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1020-0' for key 'PRIMARY' 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1022-1021' for key 'PRIMARY' 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1023-1021' for key 'PRIMARY'

is there any thing wrong with structure of the CSV file & values inside it ?

Comment: Does the error not give you enough information? Duplicate entry '1018-0' for key 'PRIMARY' seems to explain it all. The primary key must be unique but maybe yours are not unique? Without seeing the rest of the csv I can only speculate on this ofcourse

Comment: Of course i know the meaning of duplicate Primary Key,
but what i am wondering about why the feeds module when importing taxonomies gives this error, so it should be something wrong with my CSV structure & my question is more concerned about how to use the GUID & the parent GUID in importing taxonomies.

Comment: I have never imported multi level taxonomies the way you are trying. I have only done it in a "parent term>>child term" structure. If you are able to get your CSV in this sructure, you will be able to use the feeds tamper module along with the module I have posted in comment #40 at: https://drupal.org/node/1319278#comment-6967716